# Removing Attribute from JavaScript Object, Returned by Mongoose's "findOneAndUpdate" Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm writing a simple server in JavaScript on Node.js, which (among other things) allows the user to manage their account (basic CRUD functionality, etc). The server is connected to a MongoDB instance, using Mongoose to manage the connection and data.

Models in Mongoose have a method called `findOneAndUpdate()`, which does exactly what you think it does: queries the database for the first document returned and updates said document based on parameters you passed. It then returns the new, updated document to the user. It works exactly as intended and I have no problem with it.

However, I don't want ALL of the user data returned. Specifically, I'd like to omit the `_id` and `password` fields. Since the object returned by MongoDB is a basic JavaScript object, I assumed that I'd be able to remove those attributes by calling `delete object.attribute`. Unfortunately, for some reason that's not working.

Here's my code that updates the user information:

```
case "update":
  User.findOneAndUpdate({"token": header.token}, body, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    } else {
      delete user["_id"];
      delete user["password"];
      return callback(null, new SuccessEnvelope(user));
    }
  });
  break;
```

For clarity, an `Envelope` (in this case, a `SuccessEnvelope`) is a bundle of information that the client and server need in order to facilitate communication. Similar-ish to a TCP packet. Anyhow, I digress...

For example, if I wanted to update my username from "joe_bob" to "jim_bob", I'd send this to the server:

`{"header": "type": "user", "method": "update", "token": "IM_A_TOKEN_GAIS_SRSLY"}, "body": {"username": "jim_bob"}}`

And while the user's username is updated successfully, this is what I get in return:

`{"header": {"type": "success"}, "body": {"__v": 0, "_id":"SOME_NUMERICAL_ID", "email": "joe_bob@email.com", "password": "SUPER_SECURE_PASSWORD_HASH_COME_AT_ME_NSA", "token": "IM_A_TOKEN_GAIS_SRSLY", "username": "jim_bob"}}`

As you can see, `_id` and `password` are still there. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Set select: false in the schema for properties usually not wanted

mongodb allows queries to specify which properties the database should send back in the response objects. Mongoose supports this with several things including explicit field lists as well as in the schemas the notion that each property can be selected by default or not. So for this use case the best thing to do is set your password field to deselected by default:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  passwordHash: {type: String, select: false}
  ...
});
```

Then you know it will never come back automatically. However, when you actually go to process a login request you do need it, in which case you explicitly request it:

```
User.findOne({email: theEmail}, '+passwordHash', callback);
```

## For the annoying _id property, use schema transforms

The _id thing causes lots of folks headaches. Mongoose addresses this directly in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject):

```
// specify the transform schema option
if (!schema.options.toObject) schema.options.toObject = {};
schema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  // remove the _id of every document before returning the result
  delete ret._id;
}
```

Note that in the comments OP reports successfully doing `select: false` for `_id`. If that works without issues, that's a nice clean solution. I haven't tried it, but I'm worried it may break some things.

Comment: Also, to add onto this, I ended up explicitly creating an "_id" attribute in the schema, and changing the "select" property to false, much like what you did with your "passwordHash" attribute.

Comment: To add back multiple, separate them in the second parameter with spaces: `'+prop1 +prop2'`

Comment: Where does `callback()` defined?

Answer (score 58):

The `user` parameter that is returned from the call is an instance of a `Model`, in this case, the `User`.

If you want to use it as a raw JavaScript object, then you'd need to convert it using `toObject`. This returns a plain-old JavaScript object. With that, you can use `delete` and remove whatever properties you'd like.

```
user = user.toObject(); // swap for a plain javascript object instance
delete user["_id"];
delete user["password"];
return callback(null, new SuccessEnvelope(user));
```

Comment: +1 I didn't realize `toObject()` existed, we were using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));` prior to finding this.

Comment: Oh man. Converting my object(?) into an object did the trick. Irreal but it works! I could have spent the week on this. Thank you so much :)

Comment: It works! just mentions that it have to be done in each result e.g:  `obj = results[i].toObject();` where `i` is the index of a loop.